# How to write html string to a asp Lable which is showing as text instend of HTML object?

Tags: asp.net

I want to show some html string in text in my asp web, however it is creating some html object.

```
mylab.Text = "<br/>";
```

Comment: What's the control you are using?? By the way, what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @AT-2016 It is a asp:Lable. I want to show the <br/> in pure text instead of a html breaking line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following easily:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Finally do the following:

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode("<title>ASP.NET Tutorial - Label Display HTML</title><br/>");
```

For more, see this: [Display HTML Tags in an ASP.NET Label](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2013/11/aspnet-example-label-display-html.html)